# Is using OAuth2 for authentication instead of authorization a bad idea?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm reading from a lot of sources out in the web that OAuth2 is made for authorization and using it to authenticate is a bad pattern/idea. But no one actually explains why it is. Is it insecure, is it hard to implement or what?

Comment: [This answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/44614/8340) should explain things.

Comment: Not really, it explains how OpenId and OAuth work, but it is still not clearly explaining why i shouldn't use OAuth2 (or OpenId Connect) to authenticate users.

Comment: How are you intending to authenticate using OAuth2? Please add some details to your question.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/126549/8340) help?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 is used for application level authorization and not for user level authentication.

Imagine that you build an api and a front end and you only want that front end to be able to access the api while all other requests are denied. That's a valid scenario for OAuth2 usage.